# Promises does not wait resolve or reject - javascript - ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refresh-token

I use to token authentication for my react spa app. Before I CRUD process, I check refresh token expiration time. If refresh token is valid, No problem but If is'nt valid it, I send old refresh token and receive new refresh and access token from server before crud.
No problem until this point.

Problem is the refresh mechanism completes without waiting for the response from the server.

currentUser store the token value.
I check null control for token and then if expiration time not valid, I send old refresh token.

At this point the function returns without waiting for the response of the **authenticationService.createAccessTokenByRefreshToken** function. Function must be wait this function because If access token is not valid, I need new one.

Why does the function end without waiting?

```
export function authHeader() {
    var authorization = {
        Authorization: ''
    };

    var currentUser = authenticationService.currentUserValue;

    if (currentUser && currentUser.token) {
        const refreshToken = currentUser.refreshToken;
        const expiration = currentUser.expiration;
        var moment = require('moment');
        var now = moment();

        if (moment(now).isAfter(expiration)) {
            authenticationService.createAccessTokenByRefreshToken(refreshToken).then((res) => {
                authorization.Authorization = `Bearer ${res.data.token}`;
                return Promise.resolve(authorization);
            });
        }
        else {
            authorization.Authorization = `Bearer ${currentUser.token}`;
            return Promise.resolve(authorization);
        }

        //return { Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser.token}` };
    } else {
        return Promise.reject(authorization);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please start using `async` `await`. It makes your life easier and much readable code with fewer bugs. Let me know if the following works fine for you :)

```
const moment = require("moment");

const authHeader = async () => {
  try {
    const authorization = {
      Authorization: ""
    };

    const currentUser = authenticationService.currentUserValue;

    if (currentUser && currentUser.token) {
      const refreshToken = currentUser.refreshToken;
      const expiration = currentUser.expiration;
      const now = moment();

      if (moment(now).isAfter(expiration)) {
        const authResponse = await authenticationService.createAccessTokenByRefreshToken(
          refreshToken
        );
        authorization.Authorization = `Bearer ${authResponse.data.token}`;
      } else {
        authorization.Authorization = `Bearer ${currentUser.token}`;
      }
    }

    return authorization;
  } catch (err) {
    return err;
  }
};

export default authHeader;
```

Comment: Can you provide more info about what doesn't work precisely?

Comment: when i use your solutions, program could'nt see autheader function, 
import { authHeader } from '../helpers/auth-header';

Because of export default autHeader, The program perceives it as a component.

Comment: Hi @CoderDeneme, the program doesn't perceive it as a component. This is how default imports work. A module exported as default should be imported as `import authHeader from '../helper/auth-header'` rather than `named` imports. Please change the import as above mentioned.

Comment: Your solution gives the same error. ------ >>>> Uncaught (in promise) name.toUpperCase is not a function,

Comment: Can you paste your authentication service in the code sandbox or here? I can be able to debug for you!

Comment: Can you update your sandbox to have `helpers` directory as well?

Comment: I'm trying to get a new token using the refresh token.

Comment: I have updated the sandbox -> https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-ritchie-6xb57. Please make sure in your API the cors is enabled. I was not able to test as I don't have the actual API. Let me know in case there are more issues.

Comment: I got the same error, when i call the autHeader function from axios header ex -->>
    return axios.get('/api/Tables/GetInitialModel', { headers: async () => await authHeader().then((res) => res) }).catch(handleResponse);


Uncaught (in promise) name.toUpperCase is not a function

Comment: Updated again. It is not due to `authHeader`. It is due to the wrong Axios post configuration for `createAccessTokenByRefreshToken`. I am cannot exactly pinpoint as I don't have the end to end code to debug!

Comment: I don't change anything, you can see it services-->> otherservices.js

Comment: I dont think so due to axios, because I have a acces token after login so did not expiration yet. When I call the initial load model with axios, I got the same error. not problem that function createAccessTokenByRefreshToken

Comment: Please follow the updated code properly. `/api/..` are relative APIs so I don't have a server to do an actual get request. Please follow the code properly and use `async` `await` properly rather than `headers: async () => await authHeader().then((res) => res)`. Looking forward for a positive reply

Comment: Now this gone be work but This time there was a conflict in the code. I add my context api your sandbox --->>> https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-leaf-l2lrf
When I post in post proccess for example-------

                tableService.modelPost('UpdateEntity',model).then((res) => {
                    dispatch({ type: Update_Entity, payload: { basket: res.data, additionId: model.additionId} });
                    sendEntity(state.firmId, res.data, UpdateEntity, model.additionId, state.connectionId);
                })
After modelPost, dispatch work then sendEntity has gave me error.

Comment: First error is --> Cannot read property 'FIRMID' of null, you can see on my context api.
FIRMID information comes from the token. If we assume that we have solved this error, this time it gives an error in the other part. This part is sendEntity actualy send to signal on my hubserver. sendEntity function gave me unauthorize error. Before calling the function(sendEntity), we did the refresh.

Comment: Hi @CoderDeneme, can you mark the answer as done as the parent question has been solved and it works the way it is supposed to work! In parts of the related questions can you please raise another question, I would try to help you out there! Hope it makes sense to you as the comments are getting really long and it is very hard to follow

Comment: Hi thank you for your response, I ask the new question -----------------https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58720210/the-refresh-token-gives-an-unauthorized-post-error-after-issuing-a-new-token-re

Answer (score 5):

```
if (moment(now).isAfter(expiration)) {
  authenticationService.createAccessTokenByRefreshToken(refreshToken).then((res) => {
    authorization.Authorization = `Bearer ${res.data.token}`;
    return Promise.resolve(authorization);
  });
}
```

This block of code needs a return statement. At the moment it's implicitly returning undefined. Also, a small thing: if you're in a `.then` you don't need to do `Promise.resolve(authorization),` you can just return `authorization`. The `.then` creates a new promise for you.

```
if (moment(now).isAfter(expiration)) {
  return authenticationService.createAccessTokenByRefreshToken(refreshToken)
    .then((res) => {
      authorization.Authorization = `Bearer ${res.data.token}`;
      return authorization;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks man but when I use that the function forexamp. -->>     return axios.get('/api/Tables/GetInitialModel', { headers: authHeader }).catch(handleResponse); the gave me that errors --->> Uncaught (in promise) name.toUpperCase is not a function